# TYPO3: Multiple checkboxes for FE Manager

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-extensions

I've changed the purpose of the `gender` field for the `fe_users`, which comes with `femanager`.
The user is now allowed to select both items instead of just one. No worries, the user can select different options about his account, not multiple genders ;)

Saving in the backend works, but I can't get to run it in the frontend.

> **Error Message:** No converter found which can be used to convert from `array` to `string`.

I just edited the model from femanager directly because it's the easiest way, for now.

> ext/femanager/Classes/Domain/Model/User.php

```
class User extends FrontendUser
{
    /**
     * initializes this object
     *
     * @param array $gender
     */
    public function __construct($gender = array()) {
        $this->setGender($gender);
    }

    /**
     * gender
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $gender;

    /**
     * Returns the gender
     *
     * @return array $gender
     */
    public function getGender()
    {
        return unserialize($this->gender);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the gender
     *
     * @param array $gender
     * @return User
     */
    public function setGender(array $gender)
    {
        $this->gender = serialize($gender);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Any ideas what's not working?

Answer (score 1):

You define your variable `$gender` as `string`. It should be `array` instead.